# What am I missing in this integration?

Tags: numerical-integration

Trying to solve diff.eq.has led me to:

```
{a, b} = {6, 7}
Do[With[{solve = 
      NSolve[{0.8 p (y^0.2/x^0.2) + x (x - 2 a)/(x - a)^2 == 0, 
        0.2 p (x^0.8/y^0.8) + y (y - 2 b)/(y - b)^2 == 0, 
        p^-2 == x^0.8 y^0.2, 0 <= x <= a, 0 <= y <= b}, {p, x, y}]}, 
    k = Extract[solve, {1}]; l = Extract[solve, {2}]]
   a = a + 0.001 (k + l) a;
 b = b + 0.001 b k l, {100}]
{a, b}
```

but don't understand, why it fails?

Comment: When you have a problem like this, try to construct a *minimal* example that shows the problem.  Break the code into pieces and check what each piece gives separately.  You will likely find the problem on your own.  This example is far from minimal; as a start, do only one iteration instead of 100 and check the values of all your variables.

Comment: Your expression `l = Extract[solve, {2}]` does not work: there is no second part to the solution that is returned by `NSolve`. You also have syntax errors in the code you posted: you probably need a `;` after the closing square bracket for `With`.